# Perfect infinitive

Tags: infinitives, perfect-aspect

what is a perfect infinitive? when we should use it?

Before I turn 40, I want to have written a book. VS Before I turn 40, I want to write a book.

what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I turn 40, I want to have written a book.

"to have + pp" precedes the verb in a main clause: one tense faster than main clause tense.

I want to have written a book means

you already finished a book before you turn 40.

Before I turn 40, I want to write a book means

you just want to write a book(not focused on finishing but just hoping to write something before you turn 40).